# How to merge 2 parameter values to filter a field in tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to merge the values of 2 parameters. Both parameters have items of the same length, for ex: 2019, 2018 and 2017.

```
Parameter 1
2019
2018 <- User Selected
2017

Parameter 2
2019
2018
2017 <- User Selected
```

I do have a field called Year of values 2019, 2018 and 2017. From the value selected in the 2 parameters above, I want the Year field to be filtered. 
In the above example, Year should be filtered with 2018 and 2017.

How shall I proceed?

Comment: Can you just make a calculated field, `[Year of Values] = [Parameter 1] OR [Year of Values] = [Parameter 2]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56150615/how-to-merge-2-parameter-values-to-filter-a-field-in-tableau#comment98930596_56150615) worked for me

```
[Year of Values] = [Parameter 1] OR [Year of Values] = [Parameter 2]
```